# How can we add prediction region to ROC curve in package mada?

Tags: r

Consider the code below for drawing ROC curve in package mada:

```
data(AuditC)
fit.reitsma <- reitsma(AuditC)
plot(fit.reitsma)
```

This gives a graph like this:
[image: ROC curve in package mada]

I know that there's an option `predict` with the description: "logical, draw prediction region?" in `reitsma`. The problem is that I have no idea how to use this option to add the prediction region to the plot.

Comment: I guess you meant: `plot(fit.reitsma)` and then you should try: `plot(fit.reitsma, predict = TRUE)`

Comment: Yes, it was a typo and I corrected it to `plot(fit.reitsma)`. Your proposed code works pretty well!